# Swift generic data conversion function

Tags: swift, generics

I'd like to create a generic function to convert stored Data to different data types like:

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

func represent<T>(_ data: Data) -> T? {

    switch T.self {

    case is UIImage:
        guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else { return nil }
        return image
    case is AVAudioPlayer:
        guard let audio = try? AVAudioPlayer(data: data) else { return nil }
        return audio

    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Now I get "Cast from 'T.Type' to unrelated type 'UIImage'/'AVAudioPlayer' always fails". What's wrong here? Thank you.

Comment: There's no point of unwrapping the `image`/`audio` variable the way you do. When they're nil, you're returning nil, and when they're not, you return them In that case, you can just return their value directly

Comment: This function is not an unwrapper — I'm going to construct a protocol and I just need a generic function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use protocols here, rather than locking yourself into a fixed, non-extensible number of supported types (those you hard-coded in your switch statement):

```
import UIKit
import AVKit

protocol DataInitializable {
    init?(data: Data) throws
}

extension UIImage: DataInitializable {}
extension AVAudioPlayer: DataInitializable {}

extension Data {
    func decode<T: DataInitializable>() -> T? {
        do {
            return try T(data: self)
        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code? where is imageData coming from? the only parameter there is data. The same applies to audioData. Btw casting from `Data` to `UIImage` will always fail. And if it could succeed why would you initialize a new object? You would just return it.

Comment: @LeoDabus No lol, i'm going through it right now, I realize this was way off lol

Comment: Shorter: `return try? T(data: self)`

Comment: @Yannick That makes the resulting expression have type `T??`. You could do: `return (try? T(data: self)).flatMap{ $0 }`, but it's way less clear to those unfamiliar with optional's flatmap

Comment: @Alexander you are right, my bad. Yes, I also prefer the solution in your answer to the one in the comment!